# myFile.isFile() or myFile.isDirectory() is there any third type of function possible?

Tags: java, java-io

I was writing a common function to check if the variable contains a file or a directory. So I came up with an idea to check it using a boolean return-type function. something like this :

```
function boolean checkFileOrDirectory(File myFile){
    // Assume file already exist
    if(myFile.isDirectory()){
        //myFile is a directory
        return true;
    } else {
        //myFile is a file
        return false;
    }
}
```

I was wondering about the accuracy of this function. I would really appreciate if anyone can tell me will there be any kind of file types which does not come under both isFile() or isDirectory() ?

Comment: `"Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a **normal** file. A file is normal if it is not a directory and, in addition, satisfies other system-dependent criteria"`. That's from the docs of `isFile`. Maybe you just have to look for those exceptional cases where the file is not "normal"

Comment: `checkFileOrDirectory` name of method does not accurately describe its functionality

Comment: If it doesn't exist, [they'll both return false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14853402/1553851).

Comment: how about file.exists(); ?

Comment: I made it clear that the file exists, by commenting up. @ErnestKiwele I will surely look into not "normal" files, where should i start?

Comment: ok, so you are wondering if there might be a third type? directory, file, [something else]? how would you consider this possible?

Comment: I am asking if there are any files which java cannot read as a file or as a directory or return true for both? @Stultuske please check this question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853402/both-file-isfile-and-file-isdirectory-is-returning-false?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MohdNaved did you check it? in a comment on the answer, the OP claims that .exists() returns false, in that case, indeed, both .isDirectory() and .isFile() will return false

Comment: Yes, I saw it now, thanks @Stultuske

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "file" could be something like a symlink. Whether or not the distinction between a file and a symlink to a file is important depends upon your application.

---

Using boolean to represent "is something or something else" is a bad idea, because it's not clear what "true" or "false" mean.

Even if you remember that "true" means "is a directory", "false" logically means "is not a directory"... And so the reader is left wondering "well, I know it's not a directory, but what *is* it?"

And the very fact you are asking the question demonstrates this.

Consider using an enum instead:

```
enum Kind { DIRECTORY, FILE }
```

Not only is this self-documenting (you will have code saying something like "if this is a file/else if this is a directory"), it leaves the possibility of adding additional types in the future.

Comment: Thanks for giving it time to explain. Can you please also write the sample code? I never played with enum before.